# Get object class datetime from sqlalchemy query result

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I try go get datetime object class from sqlalchemy query like this:

```
curr_date = engine.execute("SELECT getdate() ").fetchall()
dt = [d.strptime('%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S') for d in curr_date]
```

and get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
dt = [d.strptime('%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S') for d in curr_date]
AttributeError: Could not locate column in row for column 'strptime'
```

Please, advise, how to fix it?

Comment: `curr_date` has rows, even if there's just one, so `d` will be a whole row

Comment: @JiříBaum thanks, "fetchone()" helped

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I solved:

```
curr_date = engine.execute("SELECT getdate() ").fetchone()
print(curr_date[0])
```